# why i can't get all first td in one selector in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

why i have to do :

```
 $('.inout tbody').find('tr:first td:first')
 //return => Object[td, td, td, td]
```

instead of

```
 $('.inout tbody tr:first td:first')
 //return => Object[td]
```

why does't have the same result? it's the pseudo element ":first" the problem?

EDIT AWNSER:

The truth response is: :first != :first-child ;)

```
 $('.inout tbody tr:first-child td:first-child')// works !
```

Comment: What does your markup look like? How many tables are on the page?

Answer (score 6):

`:first` return the first element on the stack. I guess you are looking for every first-child.

Try this :

```
$('.inout tbody tr:first-child td:first-child')
```

For reference:

> [:first-child Selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)
>
> > While `:first` matches only a single element, the `:first-child` selector can match more than one: one for each parent. This is equivalent to `:nth-child(1)`.

Comment: No... I want all first td, in first row (tr) of all my table (.inout)

so :first on tr is require !  " $('.inout tbody').find('tr:first td:first')" give me the good output, but i don't understand why have to do this in 2 times...

Comment: @Matrix  So, use `tr:first-child` instead. There can be many `:first-child` but only one `:first`.

Comment: I think he wants the first `<td>` in the first `<tr>` of every table. That's why the `.find()` version works properly: it repeats the search for each table body.

Comment: Ah i see, thanks for clearing it up i was very confused.

Comment: nice, it's that ! The truth response is: :first != :first-child ;)  "$('.inout tbody tr:first-child td:first-child')" works !

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for different things:

```
$('.inout tbody').find('tr:first td:first')
```

Is asking for the first `td` of the first `tr` for each element in `$('.inout tbody')`.

```
$('.inout tbody tr:first td:first')
```

Whereas this is asking for the first `td` of the first `tr` out of all of them.

---

The following selector will return an array of first tds:

```
$('.inout tbody tr:first-child td:first-child');
```

[This jsFiddle may be useful for verifying this](http://jsfiddle.net/9k46a/1/)

Answer (score -1):

because your second selector will select :

```
.inout > tbody > tr:first > td:first'
```

You should change it to:

```
 $('.inout tbody tr:first , .inout tbody td:first')
```

Comment: That result set will include both `tr` and `td` elements... which is not the desired output.